# Accidently use "mv" command on home directory

Tags: ubuntu, mv, cd-command

I was in my home directory and then I typed

```
cd .icons/a_folder/
```

For a weird moment, I typed

```
mv ../..
```

instead of

```
cd ../..
```

I do not know why I made that mistake, but since `../..` was my home directory
at that moment, and although it gave me the error

```
 mv: missing destination file operand after '../..'
```

I still would like to ask whether the command `mv ../..` has messed up my home directory or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mv: missing destination file operand after '../..'
```

is a “fatal” error, [`mv`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mv.html) doesn’t do anything if it doesn’t have at least two arguments. Your home directory wasn’t altered.